# Is my code overdesigned? Does it rely too heavily on interfaces?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, xna

**Context:**

I am using XNA to create a simple game / learning project.

**Problem:**

I have three interfaces, each with a different purpose in mind. However, the way I use them, as well as their implementations, makes me feel as if my code is overdesigned and poorly thought out, so I am looking for better approaches, if possible.

- `IGrid<T>` is *intended* to wrap a 2-dimensional array, exposing only the Size and indexer.
- `IChunk<T>` is *intended* to be a grid object with a predetermined size.
- `IMesh<T>` is *intended* to be a grid, but with several methods to manipulate and transform the data.

**Interfaces:**

```
public interface IGrid<T>
{
    Point Size { get; }
    T this[int x, int y] { get; set; }
}

public interface IChunk<T> : IGrid<T>
{
}

public interface IMesh<T> : IGrid<T>
{
    IMesh<T> Clone();
    IMesh<T> Flip(bool horizontal, bool vertical);
    IMesh<T> Rotate(bool clockwise);
    IMesh<T> Slice(Rectangle value);
    IMesh<T> Slice(int x, int y, int width, int height);
    IMesh<T> Transpose();
}
```

The idea is that I would use `IGrid` to create a "custom array" which could be inherited from. `IChunk` would hold a finite part of the world, breaking it apart for easier/segmented access, while `IMesh` would let me define a heightmap (with T:float), for example, and let me merge and manipulate them very easily (for generating terrain and the like).

**Classes:**

A secondary concern is defining custom operators for my Mesh class, in such a way that they could easily be added, subtracted, multiplied, etc. Now, because operator overloading involves static methods, it can't really be inherited in an elegant way.

I had tried a pattern in which I made an abstract MeshBase class that defined the operators, which called protected and abstract methods as handlers for the operations, but because of the typing involved, simply adding three meshes together involved heavy usage of casting. Needless to say, it was messy and almost unusuable.

My current solution is to do something like the following to have more control over the manipulation:

```
public class Mesh<T> : Grid<T>, IMesh<T>
{
    public Mesh(int x, int y)
        : base(x, y)
    {
    }

    // Clone(), Flip(), Rotation(), Slice(), Transpose() methods here
}

public class FloatMesh : Mesh<float> // Used as a heightmap!
{
    // Add the values of the two meshes together, creating a new mesh
    public static FloatMesh operator +(FloatMesh a, FloatMesh b) { }

    // Add the value of "b" to every element of "a", creating a new mesh
    public static FloatMesh operator +(FloatMesh a, float b) { }     
}

public class Vector2Mesh : Mesh<Vector2> // Possibly used for sampling perlin noise
{
    // Add the values of two meshes together, creating a new mesh
    public static Vector2Mesh operator +(Vector2Mesh a, Vector2Mesh b) { }

    // Apply the XY values of "b" to every element of "a", creating a new mesh
    public static Vector2Mesh operator +(Vector2Mesh a, Vector2 b) { }

    // Apply the value of "b" to each XY value of every element of "a", creating a new mesh
    public static Vector2Mesh operator +(Vector2Mesh a, float b) { }
}
```

Obviously, I would need to define these operators for every specific type I wanted to use. Nothing is stopping the user from making a Mesh themselves, if they're only interested in Transpose(), etc., but using a more derived class offers the ability to use convenient operators in addition to the transformation methods.

**Conclusion:**

Anyways, I am interested in whatever feedback you guys can offer. Like I said, I don't know if I made this in a very roundabout way, or if there is an easier/simpler way of accomplishing what I want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mostly a design review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need the `IMesh<T>` interface, because it only provides methods that can operate on an `IGrid`.

I think that to save you a whole lot of code duplication, you need to re-think your approach. Consider the potential differences between `FloatMesh` and `Vector2Mesh` with regards to the `Rotate` implementation, 99% of the code would be the same - the looping and assignments would be very similar, if not exactly duplicate.

Put as much code as possible into a generic implementation of it, for the `Rotate` method I think you can have the implementation in `Grid<T>`, and that it can use the `T` to assign to various fields.

As for the differences, I think you should consider the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). What you need to provide is *strategies* for several operations. *Possible* methods for the strategy pattern (I don't think you need all of these) are:

- void Set(MeshPosition position, T value)
- T Get(MeshPosition position)
- Add(T value1, T value2)
- Add(T value1, float value2)

Note that I think `public static Vector2Mesh operator +(Vector2Mesh a, Vector2Mesh b) { }` would duplicate a lot of code, so for this operator you should loop through the mesh / grid and only use the `Add(T value1, T value2)` method to add the values together.

Answer (score 4):

> *Is my code overdesigned?*

I think so ;)

---

> `IChunk<T>` is intended to be a grid object with a predetermined size.
>
> ```
> public interface IChunk<T> : IGrid<T>
> {
> }
> ```

But a grid is already a *grid object with a predetermined size*:

> ```
> public interface IGrid<T>
> {
>     Point Size { get; }
>     T this[int x, int y] { get; set; }
> }
> ```

I don't think you need `IChunk<T>`. Why not just use a `IGrid<T>`?

---

`IGrid<T>` is redundant here:

> ```
> public class Mesh<T> : Grid<T>, IMesh<T>
> ```

Because `IGrid<T>` is already specified by `IMesh<T>`, you can't implement `IMesh<T>` without implementing all of `IGrid<T>`, because `IMesh<T> : IGrid<T>`.

---

I might be wrong, but it seems to me that "adding up" two *terrains* is a non-trivial operation that would be best rendered as a full-fledged *method* than in an operator for the terrain itself. Can you make an operator `async`?

Comment: Well, my reasoning was that a Chunk is a *special* kind of Grid, hence the overlap. At least, the classes will vary more than the interface, I suppose. The part with `Mesh<T> : Grid<T>, IMesh<T>` is referred to the base implementation of Grid (not provided), not the interface. Thus, it's not exactly redundant (or is it?). Are operators not guaranteed to be async? I might offload it to a method in that case.

Comment: @KyleBaran Personally, I'd just create a sealed class `Mesh<T>` and use that. If you want `Chunk`, see how [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) is implemented, since it will be a similar thing. Are you *really* going to have multiple implementations of that interface, or would just one generic implementation suffice? You're not wrapping any 'external resources' in that interface either, so no mocking should be necessary for testing...